# Counting the Primitive Operators

Tags: java, operators, primitive

I have the following psuedo code:

```
Algorithm 4.1. PrefixAverages1(X)
Input: X, a 1-D numerical array of size n
1) Let A = an empty 1-D numerical array of size n
2) For i = 0 to n-1 
3)    Let s = X[0]  
4)    For j = 1 to I 
5)       Let s = s + X[j] 
6)    End For
7)   Let A[i] = s /(i+1) 
8) End For
Output: An n-element array A of numbers such that A[i]
    is the average of elements X[0],X[1], … ,X[i]
```

This was my attempt at counting the primitive operators:

```
1) -
2) n-1
3) 2
4) n
5) 4
6) -
7) 5
8) -
```

And here is my T(n): 4n^2+5n-9

Can someone please let me know if I was wrong in any of my steps? Thanks for the help!

EDIT: I think line 2 might be n and not n-1... can anyone confirm this?

Comment: n-1 , 2, n are operands if im not wrong ?

Comment: I believe so, I've been racking my brain all night over this so much that I'm starting to forget everything else D:

Comment: Line 2 is correct at n-1, and your algorithm looks correct. But I don't understand what you are asking for the rest of it.

Comment: So did I calculate the T(n) correctly: 4n^2+5n-9? I was just really worried I messed up somewhere and either counted the primitive operators wrong or messed up when working out the total number of operations.